Not able to see my android app in Alarms and reminder
I am using following permission:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
But I am not able to see my application in Alarms and reminder page. And using following code for navigating Alarms page:
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM);
intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null));
startActivity(intent);

Allow settings alarms and reminders toggle is grated out and user is not able to toggle option.
App should be shown in alarms and reminder setting.
